# How to make a grid of fixed size even when zooming?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i would like to create a map that only contains a plane of tiles that are being populated with infos.
I would like to create a grid, and for that i started by using

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl: false,}).setView([0, 0], 3);


L.GridLayer.GridMap = L.GridLayer.extend({
    createTile: function (coords) {
        var tile = document.createElement('div');

        tile.style.outline = '2px solid black';
        tile.style.borderRadius = '5px';
        return tile;
    }
});

L.gridLayer.gridMap = function(opts) {
    return new L.GridLayer.GrdMap(opts);
};

map.addLayer( L.gridLayer.gridMap() );
```

However, these tiles changes size when zooming out, while i would like them to shrink when zooming out.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: `minZoom` and `minNativeZoom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IvanSanchez said, i just have to use minNativeZoom and maxNativeZoom. Thanks a lot !